# SWIFT 3 - I need to create a way to select a relation to an item and then save it

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, relationship

I need to create a way to get the selected value from the Table view as a relationship to the text entered in the UITextField and save when clicking the save button. Here are the way i organized the views and the code:

[Views and what i need to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEHV5.png)

[Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9NXd.png)

**This is the view controller to the add view.**

```
import UIKit

class addDisciplinasViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    var materias: [Materia] = []
    var selectedIndex: Int!

    var filteredData: [Materia] = []

    var teste = ["teste","teste2"]

    func fetchData() {

        do {
            materias = try context.fetch(Materia.fetchRequest())

            filteredData = materias

        } catch {
            print("Couldn't Fetch Data")
        }

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        fetchData()
    }

    var selectedMAT: String?

    @IBOutlet var itemEntryTextView: UITextView?

    @IBAction func cancel(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func saveContact(_ sender: Any) {

        if (itemEntryTextView?.text.isEmpty)! || itemEntryTextView?.text == "Digite o nome da matéria..."{
            print("Sem dados")

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Por favor, escreva algo!", message: "Sua matéria ficou vazia.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default) { action in

            })

            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        } else {

            let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
            let newEntry = Disciplina(context: context)
            newEntry.name = itemEntryTextView?.text!


            (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).saveContext()

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        itemEntryTextView?.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.text = ""
        textView.textColor = UIColor.white
    }

    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        if (text == "\n") {
            textView.resignFirstResponder()
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}


extension addDisciplinasViewController: MateriaPiclerDelegate {

    func didSelectMateria(materia: Materia) {
        //
    }

}
```

**This is the view controller to the table view with the entities i need to relate.**

```
import UIKit

protocol MateriaPiclerDelegate: class {
    func didSelectMateria(materia: Materia)
}

class selectMateriaViewController : UITableViewController {

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    var items: [Materia] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 10
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        fetchData()
    }

    func fetchData() {

        do {
            items = try context.fetch(Materia.fetchRequest())
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } catch {
            print("Couldn't Fetch Data")
        }

    }

}

extension selectMateriaViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row].name

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        //
    }


}
```

So basically it's a study tracking app where the user adds the Subject (Materia) in another views and then adds the Topic (Disciplina) and select its patent Subject in this view. But i can't figure out how to get the Subject selected from the table and save the entry and the relationship between these 2 items.

How can i do this?

Comment: Can you show the code for addDisciplina view controller?

Comment: @user1000 Sure, i edited the question with the addDisciplinasViewController. Thank you

Comment: Have you solved the problem yet?

Comment: @user1000 i did solve one of the problems, but now the data selected on the table is not going to the other view